# Jscrollpane in matlab

Tags: swing, matlab, jscrollpane, matlab-gui

I am trying to use some java gui in my matlab code. 
I want to create a Jpanel containing lots of buttons , and add this Jpanel to a JscrollPane to be able to scroll up and down, right and left through the Jpanel. 
I tried using JavaComponent() function as described in :  http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/javacomponent

here is my code:

```
[jpanel1, hpanel1] = javacomponent('javax.swing.JPanel');
[jButton1, hButton1] = javacomponent('javax.swing.JButton');
[jscroll, hscroll] = javacomponent('javax.swing.JScrollPane');

jButton1.setText('Click again!'); 
set(hButton1,'position',[5 5 50 50])
set(hpanel1,'position',[50 50 500 500],'BackgroundColor','white');
jpanel1.add(jButton1);
jscroll.add(jpanel1);
```

The panel and button are created but I can't find the scrollpane, tried setting the jscroll to visible with no results.
WHat am I missing out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use `javacomponent` once, to display the outer-most java container, i.e. `JScrollPane` in your case. Just assemble your components inside `JPanel` container and then pass that to `JScrollPane` constructor.

Note that it is safer to create your objects with [javaObjectEDT](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaobjectedt.html) so that subsequent method calls run on EDT - [otherwise you could face a deadlock / race condition](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt).

Finally, note how you can use [getpixelposition](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getpixelposition.html) and `'normalized'` units for the container created by `javacomponent` to make your `JScrollPane` fill the entire parent drawing area, and behave better on resizing.

```
jButton1 = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JButton', 'Button 1');
jButton2 = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JButton', 'Button 2');
jPanel = javax.swing.JPanel();
jPanel.add(jButton1);
jPanel.add(jButton2);
jScrollPane = javax.swing.JScrollPane(jPanel);

hFig = figure();
hParent = uicontainer('Parent',hFig);
parentPixelPos = getpixelposition(hParent);
pos = [1,1,parentPixelPos(3),parentPixelPos(4)]; % fill the parent uicontainer completely
[~, hContainer] = javacomponent(jScrollPane, pos, hParent);
set(hContainer, 'Units', 'normalized');  % better behavior on resizing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jscroll.add(jpanel1);
```

You should never add components to a scroll pane. A JScrollPane has its own custom layout manager to display the scrollbars and the viewport.

So instead you need to add the panel to the viewport:

```
jscroll.setViewportView( jpanel1 );
```

However, this may still not work as the following code looks like it is trying to set the size/location of the component which implies a null layout is being used:

```
set(hButton1,'position',[5 5 50 50])
```

Normally it is the responsibility of the layout manager to determine the size/location of a component and the scrollbars of the scrollpane will only be displayed is the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scrollpane.

I don't know that the benefit of using MatLab is. I suggest you just use normal Swing. See examples from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: yes you're right using layouts manager  is way easier. thank you